# Add Scala 3.0 SDK to IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, scalac, scala-3

Currently, the dotty compiler released its first Release Candidate and will be released in the next few months.
I updated the IntelliJ scala plugin to EarlyAccess to make it working with Scala 3.0, its problem with syntax highlighting resolved, but still, it has a problem with IntelliSense, suggestions are only scala 2.13 API and it has no idea for Scala 3.0 API and it makes hard to develop.
I tried to add the Scala 3.0 SDK manually, but it does not accept it(as the compiler jar file name in the new version changed).

[image]

Is there any possibility to add Scala 3.0 SDK to IntelliJ?

Comment: There is a change in [naming](https://dotty.epfl.ch/blog/2020/09/21/naming-schema-change.html) of Scala libraries. The issues on JetBrains is [this](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-18196)

Comment: I dislike writing it, but the best support for Scala 3 offers at the moment (February 2021) the Visual Studio Code with the Scala Metals plug-in.

Comment: @Twistleton I installed it, but even it do not support RC1: `Scala 3.0.0-RC1 is not yet supported, please downgrade to Scala 3.0.0-M3.`

Comment: @MohsenKashi It's a sad thing to hear. But RC1 was only released a few days ago. The developers might need a few days to adapt the plug-in for the new version.

Comment: @Twistleton it's not only that, I downgrade to M3, but intelisense doesn't work for TASTy modules, it only works for the main API.

Comment: @MohsenKashi Maybe we still have to be patient until everything is built in the Intellij IDEA.

Comment: @MohsenKashi Good news for us: The Metals v0.10.0 Plugin (24.02.2021) offers support for Scala 3.0.0-RC1. I wish you much success!

Answer (score 0):

Update to one of the 2022 EAP versions of IntelliJ and the EAP version of the scala plugin.
Once that's done, loading a scala3 project from build.sbt works out of the box